# Storing Push Notification Data into UserDefault iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

Working on push notification and want to store the data into UserDefault. When I checking through break point it return nil I don't know why values are nil.See my code below thanks.

```
struct PushInfo: Encodable {
    var body: String
    var title : String
    var url: String
}



var pushInfo: PushInfo?
  pushInfo?.body = data["body"] as? String ?? ""
  pushInfo?.url = data["url"] as? String ?? ""
  pushInfo?.title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
  UserDefaults.standard.setValue(pushInfo, forKeyPath: "PushInfo")
  if let pushData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "PushInfo") as? PushInfo {
   print(pushData.title)
  }
```

Comment: As of right now you have not set a value for `pushInfo` but
Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct PushInfo: Codable {
    var body: String
    var title : String
    var url: String
}

// MARK: - Codable helper
extension Encodable {
    func toString() -> String? {
        if let config = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) {
            return String(data: config, encoding: .utf8)
        }
        return .none
    }
}

extension Decodable {
    static func map(JSONString: String) -> Self? {
        try? JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: JSONString.data(using: .utf8) ?? .init())
    }
}


let pushInfo = PushInfo(body: "1", title: "2", url: "3")
UserDefaults.standard.set(pushInfo.toString(), forKey: "PushInfo")
if let str = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: PushInfo), let object = PushInfo.map(JSONString: str) {
    print("here \(object)")
}
```